cs50 scabble problem not working. can anyone help plz?
I'm doing the cs50 scrabble problems from problem set 2 and my 'point' function doesn't add points correctly. The function keeps ignoring all the 'if' and 'else if' statements even when there are char that corresponds with that 'if' statement.
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int score1 = 0;
int score2 = 0;
int point(string ply);
void compare(int pl1, int pl2);

int main(void)
{
    string ply1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string ply2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    score1 = point(ply1);
    score2 = point(ply2);
    compare(score1, score2);
}



//calculate point
int point(string ply)
{
    int score = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(ply); i++)
    {
        if(ply[i] == ('a'|'e'|'i'|'l'|'n'|'o'|'r'|'s'|'t'|'u'))
        {
            score += 1;
            printf("yes\n");
        }
        else if(ply[i] == ('d'|'g'))
        {
            score += 2;
        }
        else if(ply[i] == ('b'|'c'|'m'|'p'))
        {
            score += 3;
        }
        else if(ply[i] == ('f'|'h'|'v'|'w'|'y'))
        {
            score += 4;
        }
        else if(ply[i] == 'k')
        {
            score +=5;
        }
        else if(ply[i] == ('j'|'x'))
        {
            score += 8;
        }
        else
        (
            score += 10
        );
    }
    return score;
}

//compare score
void compare(int pl1, int pl2)
{
    if(pl1 < pl2)
    {
        printf("Player 2 won!\n");
    }
    else if(pl1 > pl2)
    {
        printf("player 1 won!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("tie\n");
    }
}

I run this in the cs50 debugger and when it came to the if function, it doesn't add anything to the score but instead just skips over.

What does the CS50 course tell you about passing arguments to functions? It should have taught you that arguments are passed by value. Which means the value in the call is copied into the functions local argument variable. Any changes you make to the functions local argument variables will be lost when the function returns.

And ply[i] == ('a'|'e'|'i'|'l'|'n'|'o'|'r'|'s'|'t'|'u') does not do what you think it does. It will evaluate ('a'|'e'|'i'|'l'|'n'|'o'|'r'|'s'|'t'|'u') using bitwise OR, creating a non-zero value. You then compare that non-zero value with ply[i].If you want to compare to multiple values, you must do multiple comparisons. Like ply[i] == 'a' || ply[i] == 'e' etc. Also note the use of the logical OR operator ||.

how should i write it so that ply[i] compare itself to these letter indiviualy and return true when it's correct. i tried to use || but it doesn't allow me to do that

"but it doesn't allow me to do that" then you did it wrong. The way SomeProgrammerDude showed it in the comment above yours, is correct. If it doesn't work for you, you need to update your question. Add the new version at the bottom, do not delete the initial code.

The problem is that you are just typing random stuff as you go and hope that's how the programming language works. But programming doesn't work like that - there's no "take a chance" and there's no trial & error. You either know how something works or you don't. In case you don't, you look it up in a book or other source of learning.

Aside: calculation error: A blank have a score of 0. point() gives it a score of 10.

The conditions you have aren't doing what you think they're doing.
First, as a reminder, char literals like 'a' are in fact just a fancy way of writing numbers - they are interpreted as their ASCII values. | is the bitwsie or operator. So when you have a statement like ply[i] == ('a'|'e'|'i'|'l'|'n'|'o'|'r'|'s'|'t'|'u'), the right side of the equality is calculated (it's equal to 127), and then ply[i] is compared to it.
The right way, syntactically, to write the condition you intended to write is as a series of logical or conditions:
if (ply[i] == 'a' ||
    ply[i] == 'e' ||
    ply[i] == 'i' || 
    ply[i] == 'l' ||
    ply[i] == 'n' ||
    ply[i] == 'o' ||
    ply[i] == 'r' ||
    ply[i] == 's' ||
    ply[i] == 't' ||
    ply[i] == 'u') {
score += 1;
}
// else if etc...

But that's very cumbersome. A neater solution could be to implement a poor-man's hashmap.
Each character from 'a' to 'z' is worth a specific amount of points. And since char literals are just fancy numbers, if you subtract 'a' from each char, you'd get numbers from 0 to 25, which can be used as array indexes.
You can create an array of point values:
const int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};
int points (char* str) {
    int score = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i) {
        score += POINTS[str[i] - 'a'];
    }
    return score;
}


Strictly speaking it isn't a good idea to teach newbies to do arithmetic on character constants, because there is strictly speaking no guarantee that a to z are adjacent (the tiresome old EBCDIC argument). Instead I'd sacrifice a few hundred bytes of ROM and make something like const uint8_t POINTS[256] = { ['a']=1, ['b']=3, ...};... score += POINTS[str[i]];. Those who fancy can add an upper case version inside that same table as well. As a bonus this also gives score zero for all non-letters.

When the tile being summed is a blank, POINTS[str[i] - 'a'] will be a problem.

@Lundin pedantic: score += POINTS[str[i]]; will be a problem when the char in  str[i] is negative.

@Mureinik well explains OP's problem.
Alterative summings, as commented by @Lundin
#include <ctype.h>

int point_alternative1(string ply) {
  static const unsigned char points[] = { ['A']=1, ['B']=3, /* 23 more */ ['Z']=10};

  int score = 0;
  for(size_t i = 0; ply[i]; i++) {
    unsigned char character = str[i];
    character = toupper(character);
    if (character < sizeof points) {
      score += points[character];
    }
  }
  return score;
}

// OR

#include <limits.h>

int point_alternative2(string ply) {
  static const unsigned char points[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = { //
      ['A']=1, ['B']=3, /* 23 more */ ['Z']=10, //
      ['a']=1, ['b']=3, /* 23 more */ ['z']=10 };

  int score = 0;
  for(size_t i = 0; ply[i]; i++) {
    score += points[(unsigned char) ply[i]];
  }
  return score;
}

// OR

#include <limits.h>

int point_alternative3(const char *s) {
  static const unsigned char points[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = { //
      ['A']=1, ['B']=3, /* 23 more */ ['Z']=10, //
      ['a']=1, ['b']=3, /* 23 more */ ['z']=10 };
  const unsigned char *us = (const unsigned char *) s;

  int score = 0;
  while (*us) {
    score += points[*us++];
  }
  return score;
}

